# VCPU hot unplug on windows on XEN

Tags: windows, cpu, xen, hypervisor, hotplugging

I have a XEN hypervisor running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter version. I can hot plug VCPUs for Windows 2008 with the following command to four VCPUs:

```
xm vcpu-set "windows_2008" 4
```

But I can not hot unplug VCPU from it with any of the following commands:

```
xm vcpu-set "windows_2008" 3
xm vcpu-set "windows_2008" 2
xm vcpu-set "windows_2008" 1
```

If any of the commands above executed, then Windows 2008 would show a popup window which says:
"AMD Opteron(TM) Processor 6234 Device is not be removable and cannot be ejected or unplugged"

Windows 2008 does not support hot unplug VCPUs or XEN does not support that?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: According note from [Microsoft official wesbite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548040.aspx), it say that CPU hot unplug is not supportted on Windows 2003 and Windows 2008.